# how to create custom installer for window application in .net

Tags: installation, window, custom-action

I want to create setup for my **window application** in .net,in which i want to asked user to **input custom connection string** at time of **installation**.how can I do it.
after digging in the matter. I have created set up project for this. now i stuck up in it.
how to move further.
any tutorial on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio setup project, you can try creating a custom dialog through which you get the connection information. Perhaps this tutorial will help:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/vsSetupCustomDialogs.aspx

If you are using another tool, mention it in your post and I will edit my answer with some suggestions.

Comment: Did the tutorial I mentioned help?